# Send email with just a jpg image

Tags: php, html, email, header

i need to send an email to some list with just a jpg as the body of the message, this are the headers i'm using, but it's not working when i add the image (instead, if i write some random text the email is sent correctly)
This is what i'm using so far:

```
message = '<img src="http://www.gulfview.info/admin/birthday_card_goes_here/birthday.jpg" width="600" height="800" />';
$subject = 'Happy Birthday from your Gulfview Friends !!';


$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Bob Fregalette <info@thegiftstores.org>' . "\r\n";




if(!mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers)){

echo $email." not sent <br>";
 }
 else {

  echo $email ."Sent succesfully<br>";
  }
```

Any hint?
Thanks

Comment: This ***will*** be filtered by most spam detection software. Just so you know...

Comment: Don't build your own mime emails. It's unreliable and painful. Use PHPMailer or Swiftmailer instead.

Comment: Define "not working."  Is the email not being sent to the SMTP server?  Is the SMTP server not sending it out?  Are users' email clients not displaying it?  I suspect the problem exists outside of the code itself.

Comment: And how do i avoid that? it's for a list of people living in a condo.... not mass mailing

Comment: David, the mail is not going through when i use $message as i stated above, instead if i use $message = "Hello world"; the email is sent and not treated as spam. I can't use phpMAILER because the host server doesn't allow it (strange, i know)

Comment: So is the email being sent with no image, or is the email not even being sent? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Also, is the missing $ in front of your message variable just a typo?

Comment: Why do you put `Content-Type: text/html` if what you want to send is `image/jpeg`?  Or do you actually want to send an HTML document containing an image link?

Comment: It would help if you posted the code that doesn't work instead the code that does work ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've assigned something to the value of $email somewhere else?

Your code works as written for me if I assign something to the $email value before this code.

If I run it without a value of $email, it has a fatal error that there's no recipient message in the message header.

Comment: i do have a valid email address on the $email variable, yes.

Comment: Are you getting a fatal error or just seeing $email not sent?